# Product image missing from backend after updating to magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-7405, file-permissions

I recently updated several sites running Magento CE 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.2.3. I noticed that product images (when uploaded now) are no longer visible in the backend - though **they are** visible on the frontend.

It seems like this is related to the new security patch.

**Edit:**

Is there a way I can resolve this? Changing the permissions on the file from 640 to 644 / 777 makes them visible.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon it's related to the following changes from 1.9.2.3:

- Files uploaded via admin panel (i.e. product image upload) are now not world readable by default (before: 777 / after: 640).
- Directories are also not world executable (before 755 / after: 750). This two can cause issues with images not appearing on the website if the webserver runs as a different user from php.

So I reckon you should double check the permissions on the files you can't view and specially check the webserver user.

Also, as you can see them on frontend and not in backend, it sounds like you may be running two different instances (one for frontend / one for backend) where frontend webserver user has the right permissions and backend one does not.